# The same cache between two .net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

We have two MVC5 Applications: `AdminPanel` and `UI`
As you can suggest one of them is for managing and entities CRUD (`AdminPanel`) and one of them is for normal website.
Both of them are in the same server and both of them have the same cache identities.

In `AdminPanel` we need to modify `UI` caches. Is it possible? if so, how? and if we can't, what is the best way to do it? 
At the other hand, What is the best way to have the same cache between some web applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't share ASP.NET cache between two servers.

But there are some other ways to do this. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585798/best-way-to-synchronize-cache-data-between-two-servers).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is about share memory between two processes, you can see detail information here.

[Shared memory between 2 processes (applications)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004790/shared-memory-between-2-processes-applications)

**What is the best way to have the same cache between some web applications?**

I think it depends, most of the modern large scale websites build their own distributed cache system with Memcached, Redis or something else. If you just have two websites running on one machine, maybe you can just use the technology Windows provide like MMF,named pipe, etc.